# Python while loop does not stop

Tags: python-2.7, date, while-loop

I am writing a script to ask user to enter a date. If it is a date format, then return the entry; otherwise, continue. But my code doesn't stop even the user input is valid. Could somebody please share some insight? Thanks!

```
def date_input(prompt):
    while True:
        date_text = raw_input(prompt)
        try:           
            datetime.datetime.strptime(date_text, '%Y-%m-%d')
            return date_text
        except:
            print('Invalid input.')
            continue
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never use `except`, always check for a specific exception:

```
except ValueError:
```

Then your real error should come through. I suspect you didn't import `datetime`.

Comment: I did try "except ValueError" before it gave me the same thing, but now i reopened the script, it is working now. Thanks!